# Specific range of numbers is given, trying to get another number within same range

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms, exponential-sum

I'm trying to calculate the width of an HTML element based on the window size.

Here's what I have. These width values (first value) accurately match with the width the HTML element must be (second value). However I need to get a formula for this to be able to set the width of the HTML correctly according to any possible window size.

window width / HTML element width

- 1663         =  1916
- 1221         =  1692
- 1119         =  1641
- 1038         =  1602
- 630          =  1396
- 1500         =  ????
- 1400         =  ????
- 2000         =  ????

I've been staring at this four hours but I just can't wrap my head around it..

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Roel

Comment: All of your equations are false. $1663$ is _not_ the same as $1916$", and the $=$ sign does _not_ mean "corresponds to, in some unspecified context-dependent way".

Answer (score 2):

Linear regression gives: $m=0.5030755166$ $c=1078.8117490$
with $R^2=0.9999778405$. This gives the desired values as

- 630  1396
- 1500 1833
- 1400 1783
- 2000 2085

Comment: Thanks Shitikanth, glad someone knows how to do this :) .. But which formula can I use to get the element width for any window width my users may be using?? How can I implement this programmatically??? - So I mean: x (element width) = <formula> 
Thanks!

Comment: y= mx+c with m and c given above (x is the window width and y is the HTML window width)

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a complete mathematics noob :P .. What does mx mean? Do i have to multiply m with x before adding it to c?  --thanks again